# I need to apply a Friedman Test on 2680 columns of data in sets of 8 columns

Tags: r, loops, statistics, apply

I have 2680 columns of data in sets of 8 columns for which I need to apply a Friedman Test on each set, so I need to apply the test 335 times. Would it be possible to loop through the code in sets of 8?

An example of the one of the sets is:

```
    X2012    X2013 X2014    X2015    X2016 X2017 X2018
[1,] 0.000000 0.000000  0.00 0.000000 0.000000  0.00 0.000
[2,] 0.000000 3.000000  0.00 0.000000 0.000000  0.00 3.000
[3,] 3.000000 3.000000  0.00 3.000000 3.000000  3.00 3.000
[4,] 2.500000 2.333333  3.00 3.000000 3.000000  2.75 3.000
[5,] 2.600000 3.000000  3.00 2.428571 3.000000  3.00 3.375
[6,] 2.891892 2.967742  3.04 2.833333 2.777778  3.00 2.840
```

with some code

```
require(PMCMRplus)
rank <- read.csv("C:/Projects/rank.csv",header=TRUE)
rank<-as.matrix(rank)
friedman.test(rank)
```

which gives as a result

```
Friedman rank sum test

data:  rank
Friedman chi-squared = 33.228, df = 6, p-value = 0.00000948
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do...  It is definitely possible to loop over all kind of sets (and subsets)...  Do I understand correctly that all these datasets are in separate files of 8 columns each and you want to loop over `read.csv` and `friedman.test`?

Comment: The data is in one file with 2680 columns.  I need to loop through all columns, but in sets of 8 (there's an id column that I've removed in the sample data above).  I just need to know how to set up the For Loop.   I also thought about using the Apply functions, but I'm not sure if that applies here.

Comment: so you mean first you test on columns 1:8, thereafter 9:16, 17:24 etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I thought maybe using sapply and applying it to columns, but how to apply it in sets of 8 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would select a subset of columns from your rank matrix.  Something like:

```
...
rank <- as.matrix(rank)
for(chunk in seq(from=1, to=ncol(rank), by=8)) {
   j <- seq(from=chunk, length.out=8);
   friedman.test(rank[,j])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and even used a For Loop incrementing the indices by 8, but I didn't trust the results.  I eventually just used brute force ...

```
require(PMCMRplus)
require(PMCMR)
rank <- read.csv("C:/Projects/rank.csv",header=TRUE)
rank<-as.matrix(rank) 
friedman.test(rank[,    2   :   8   ])
friedman.test(rank[,    10  :   16  ])
friedman.test(rank[,    18  :   24  ])
friedman.test(rank[,    26  :   32  ])
```

etc 
.
.
.

It was fairly easy to do using Excel to increment the indices and pasting all 335 tests into r.